# Django sorting based on first object of many to many field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

Here i wanted to sort the user based on the first object of car field .And For Foreign key i was doing like this and this is what i tried. `User.objects.all().order_by('car__name')`. 
But for many to many field how can i do it for the first or last object.

```
class Car(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

Comment: Well what is the first or last object? In databases the items are *unordered* so there is no such thing as a first/last related object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use annotation together with subqueries to achieve what you want, as follows:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('some_ordering')
user = User.objects.annotate(first_car_name=Subquery(cars.values('name')[1])).order_by('first_car_name')
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions